# How to add a button in right of RibbonPage tab?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ribbon

I want to add a button to right of ribbonpage tab,I know how to add it from Left,but I don't know how to locate the button in right of the tab.How can I make this?

```
<dxr:RibbonPage>
    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Caption="view">
        <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="homepage" Command="" Glyph="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=NewMail_16x16.png}" LargeGlyph="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=NewMail_32x32.png}" />
    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
    <!-- How to add button on right of the page?-->
</dxr:RibbonPage>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some sample code that demonstrates your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8,thanks,i have posted my code,please help me if you know how to make it.